# Initializing emacs with org-babel : Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function cl-member)

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I have migrated my init.el to an org-mode file, to use the flexibility of org-mode coupled with babel.

However, I cannot get it to work. I suspect some dependency error, have tried a lot of things to fix it, but I don't have the skills to understand where things go wrong :

1. here my init.el --- does nothing but calling an org file containing all the init code

   ```
   ;; from http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html#literate-programming
   ;;; init.el --- Where all the magic begins
   ;;
   ;; This file loads Org-mode and then loads the rest of our Emacs initialization from Emacs lisp
   ;; embedded in literate Org-mode files.

   ;; Load up Org Mode and (now included) Org Babel for elisp embedded in Org Mode files
   (package-initialize)
   (setq dotfiles-dir (file-name-directory (or (buffer-file-name) load-file-name)))
   (require 'org-install)
   (require 'ob-tangle)
   (org-babel-load-file (expand-file-name "emacs-and-org-init.org" dotfiles-dir))
   ```
2. this is the org file --- even minimal it throws the error

   ```
   #+TITLE: Emacs and Org init
   #+OPTIONS: toc:2 num:nil ^:nil

   #+begin_quote
     Emacs outshines all other editing software in approximately the same
     way that the noonday sun does the stars. It is not just bigger and
     brighter; it simply makes everything else vanish.

     -- Neal Stephenson, "In the Beginning was the Command Line"
   #+end_quote

   * Implementation
   This section contains all the init code.
   ** basics
   this is commented on purpose --- even commented, the use of this file throw the error "Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function cl-member)"
     #+begin_src emacs-lisp
   ;;    (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/") ;;;; this is commented on purpose --- even commented, the use of this file throw the error "Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function cl-member)"
     #+end_src

   ** the rest of the code
   - this sections is almost empty for the moment, so that this file is the minimal file that throw an error

   #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
   ;; this should appear in the emacs-and-org.el, but does not
   (message "test")
   #+END_SRC
   ```
3. and here the resulting emacs-and-org.el --- the first "org babel code section" is here, but the second is missing

   ```
   ;;    (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/") ;;;; this is commented on purpose -- even commented, the use of this file throw the error "Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function cl-member)"
   ```
4. the error thrown :

   ```
   Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function cl-member)
   ```

Who could help ?

```
M-x version
GNU Emacs 24.3.50.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.4.2) of 2013-09-29 on gkar, modified by Debian

M-x org-version
Org-mode version 8.2.1 (8.2.1-3-g35e5e5-elpa @ /home/me/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20131007/)
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's the minimal setup:

`~/emacs-and-org-init.org`:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(message "test")
#+end_src
```

`~/.emacs`:

```
(package-initialize)
(require 'ob-tangle)
(org-babel-load-file "~/emacs-and-org-init.org")
```

Start from this setup and add things incrementally until stuff breaks
(hopefully it will not:)).

By the way, you can get `cl-member` by `(require 'cl)`, if this comes up.

Comment: That's it. I've added (require 'cl) just after (package-initialize) in the .emacs you give, and it works ; even with my whole .org config file. Tks a lot!